# What does this ruby code do?

Tags: ruby

I have code here that verifies the number input for zero and floats:

```
def integer?(input)
  input.to_i.to_s == input
end

def float?(input)
  input.to_f.to_s == input
end

def valid_number?(input)
  integer?(input) || float?(input)
end

loop do # main loop
  number1 = ''
  loop do
    prompt(messages('first_number', LANGUAGE))
    number1 = Kernel.gets().chomp()

    if valid_number?(number1)
      break
    else
      prompt(messages('not_a_valid_number', LANGUAGE))
    end
  end

  number2 = ''
  loop do
    prompt(messages('second_number', LANGUAGE))
    number2 = Kernel.gets().chomp()

    if valid_number?(number2)
      break
    else
      prompt(messages('not_a_valid_number', LANGUAGE))
    end
  end
end

  result = case operator
           when '1'
             number1.to_i() + number2.to_i()
           when '2'
             number1.to_i() - number2.to_i()
           when '3'
             number1.to_i() * number2.to_i()
           else
             number1.to_f() / number2.to_f()
           end

  prompt("The answer is: #{result}")
```

What does this code do in layman's term or in an explanation that a dummy can understand?

```
def integer?(input)
  input.to_i.to_s == input
end

def float?(input)
  input.to_f.to_s == input
end

def valid_number?(input)
  integer?(input) || float?(input)
end
```

Any help here? I would appreciate if you could explain it line by line thanks!

Sorry newbie here!

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You need to narrow it down by telling us what *exactly* you *don't* understand, what you *do* understand, what your knowledge level is, etc. The code you posted uses a very large percentage of all features of Ruby, and it is completely unclear which ones you are talking about. Do you know what an object is? Do you know what a method is? Do you know what a message send is? Do you understand the difference between methods, procedures, functions and other kinds of subroutines? Do you understand dynamic ad-hoc inclusion polymorphism? Do you know what a class is?

Comment: Do you know what a method definition is? Do you know what a variable is? Do you know what an argument is? Do you know what a parameter is? Do you know what the difference and relationship between an argument and a parameter is? Do you know what a boolean is? Do you know how truthiness and falsiness are defined in Ruby? Do you know what an operator is? Do you know what a string is in Ruby? Do you know what an integer is in Ruby? Do you know what a float is in Ruby? Do you know how operator syntax relates to message sends? Do you know where to find Ruby documentation? Do you know how to read it?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 0):

In those functions `input` is transformed to a number (integer using `to_i` or float using (`to_f`)) and then back to string (with `to_s`). Then the result of those transformations is compared with the input.

It verifies if an input is a number, because if it is not, transformed string will be not equal to the original one.

For instance:

```
$ "a".to_i.to_s
=> "0"
```

because `to_i` returns 0 if string cannot be parsed to an integer (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

All it's doing is converting a string to an integer / float, converting it back to a string and comparing it to the input string. If the input was a valid integer / float, its converted value will be identical to the input. If, however the input was not a valid number, casting it to an integer or float will turn it into a zero, which when compared to the original input will be different. Here's an example:

```
irb(main):012:0> "abc".to_i.to_s
=> "0"
irb(main):013:0> "123".to_i.to_s
=> "123"
```

So as you can see the non-numeric input would fail the check.